# Oracle SQL count group by day distinct in day and days before

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct

I need help with this: I have this table:

```
DAY     WO
 1     1000
 1     1009
 1     2056
 2     1003
 2     1006
 2     1000
 3     1009
 3     6787
 4     7000
 4     7020
```

I need to group by day distinct WO, but not only in the day I'm grouping, also distinct in the days before, to obtain this:

```
DAY    WO
 1      3 (1000,1009,2056)
 2      2 (1003,1006)
 3      1 (6787)
 4      2 (7000,7020)
```

Thanks for your help

```
Sample 2:
DAY   WO
6   379157
9   379157
10  379404
10  379362
19  386118
24  386547
25  388711
25  386547
30  386547
```

Comment: Is that the literal output you want? With the WO values listed in a comma separated list in parenthesis?

Comment: Although it's not required, it would be nice.

Comment: Im not sure how your example output is excluding the `1009` value of `day` = `3`, but my answer below is otherwise what you have as your output.

Comment: The example output is excluding the 1009 value of day = 3 because the value 1009 is also in the day = 1

Comment: Ahh, I see then... I must have missed a similar exclusion on day 2 when I was reading your post earlier. I see the pattern now.

Comment: I updated my answer to take that into account. Even though you've already accepted an answer, perhaps mine will give you an alternative. Plus I included the list of `wo` values in parenthesis. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT DAY, COUNT(DISTINCT WO)
FROM (
   SELECT MIN(DAY) AS DAY, WO
   FROM mytable 
   GROUP BY WO) AS t
GROUP BY DAY
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/216087/1)

**Explanation:** The inner query delivers the *first* `Day` related to each `WO` value (if by first you mean the minimum `Day` value. The outer query can then perform a `COUNT DISTINCT` operation to get the number of distinct `WO` values per `DAY`.

**Edit:** To get *all* days returned, even those having *no* `WO`, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.DAY, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT t2.WO) wo_cnt,
       LISTAGG(t2.WO, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.WO) wo_list
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT DAY
  FROM mytable) t1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(DAY) AS DAY, WO
   FROM mytable 
   GROUP BY WO
) t2 ON t1.DAY = t2.DAY
GROUP BY t1.DAY
ORDER BY t1.DAY
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04e5e/14)

Comment: that was so smart ! Well done ! Juste missing the concat part if you want it

Comment: Thanks for your help @Giorgios Betsos. Very useful!

Comment: I have a problem with the query. Or maybe the problem is my first sample of data. With the sample 2 that I have added to the question, when I run the query, there are missing days in the resuts. The day 9 and the day 30.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `LISTAGG` to concatenate the values together, plus a little extra string concatenation for formatting:

```sql
-- START: table data mockup
with days as
(
    select 1 as "day", 1000 as "wo" from dual
    union all
    select 1 as "day", 1009 as "wo" from dual
    union all
    select 1 as "day", 2056 as "wo" from dual
    union all
    select 2 as "day", 1003 as "wo" from dual
    union all
    select 2 as "day", 1006 as "wo" from dual
    union all
    select 2 as "day", 1000 as "wo" from dual
    union all
    select 3 as "day", 1009 as "wo" from dual
    union all
    select 3 as "day", 6787 as "wo" from dual
    union all
    select 4 as "day", 7000 as "wo" from dual
    union all
    select 4 as "day", 7020 as "wo" from dual
)
-- END: table data mockup

select "day", count("wo") || ' (' || listagg("wo", ',') within group (order by "wo") || ')' "WO"
from days d1
where d1."wo" not in
(
    select d2."wo"
    from days d2
    where d2."day" < d1."day"
)
group by "day";
```

Comment: Thanks @gmiley. But my example was a data sample. My dataset is bigger. I can't build your query by hand.

Comment: The query itself works without the beginning `with` statement. Use everything outside of the `--BEGIN`/`--END` comments. I just included that to provide mocked data for a standalone executable proof. You just need to ensure the correct table and column names are being used for your actual data table.

Comment: @Madmartigan you only need from the `select` onward to the end, everything before that is a stand-in for your actual table.

Comment: OK!, Thanks @gmiley. Let me check.

Comment: It works OK, @gmiley.. But I have the same problem with the sample two I have added. The day=9 and the day =30 are missing in the final result.

Comment: 9 and 30 are both duplicates. 9 duplicates 6 and 30 duplicates 24.

Comment: Not really,  they are different days with the same WO.

Comment: That's the same pattern that excluded 1009 that I originally asked about.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.day_number, count(a.WO) as WO_count
from (
SELECT * FROM data d 
WHERE d.day_number = ( 
SELECT MIN(day_number) FROM data d2
WHERE d.WO = d2.WO

) 
) as a
group by a.day_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number` to enumerate work order occurrences, then filter out all rows except the first for each work order and count what's left.

```
SELECT day, count(*) wo
FROM (SELECT day, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY wo ORDER BY day) rn
      FROM day_wo) t
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day;
```